# tomcat port closes

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I have a Tomcat Server 7.0.54 running on port 6584 on an Amazon EC2 instance.

The server runs fine for a while but suddenly it seems to close the port on which it listens.

When it is running normally `netstat -lnp | grep <pid_of_tomcat>` gives me

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      22999/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      22999/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::6584                 :::*                    LISTEN      22999/java
```

When it suddenly stops working, the tomcat instance is still running and there is enough memory on the machine. But `netstat -lnp | grep <pid_of_tomcat>` only gives me

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      22999/java
```

This suggests that tomcat is no longer listening on the port.

How can I explain why this happens? How can I debug the situation?

Comment: Do you want to run on IPV6?

Comment: Not sure. I am using whatever is the default setting for this.

Comment: It would be good to check logs of Tomcat. File name is catalina.out for any errors.

Comment: catalina.out does not contain anything of notice

Comment: Does it happens even when you don't hit the tomcat instance. Can you check if JVM is crashing or not, if it's crashing you can notice file created in /tmp/ folder. Check with last few updated files.

Comment: The JVM does not crash. When I do `ps aux | grep tomcat`, the tomcat instance is still running. It's just that tomcat seems to no longer listen to the port.

Comment: Maybe something related to security groups? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Answer (score 1):

1. If catalina.out does not contain anything, please check the os level log file. For Linux check /var/log/messages.
2. In the netstat output you have shown earlier, is the pid the same or does it change over time ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not able to reproduce the issue now, but will check that file whenever it fails again. In the netstat the pid is the same, so that is why I say that the tomcat instance is the same, just that it no longer is listening to its port.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of thing which you can do for this is as below.

1. **Disabling** all the **ipv6** on the network devices
2. Adjusted "{tomcat_home}/bin/setenv.sh" with the following:

   ```
    export CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
   ```

Comment: Pretty sure this is not related ipv4 or ipv6

Answer (score 1):

1. check tomcat logs : catalina.out, localhost.log, etc.
2. add this `-Xrunhprof:cpu=samples,interval=10,depth=8`  to your JAVA_OPTS, and check the 
   "java.profile.txt" file generated when it happens again.
   (if you need to change some arguments, refer to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html))

Comment: Thanks. Yes I should try that

Answer (score 0):

Check If there is any cron job running at system level for apt-packages. 
if yes then remove this cron job. I think this is the problem.

Comment: Do you mean, the cron job will update tomcat while it is still running. And that might be the issue? Will check definitely.